React use hooks (useContext) inside of useReducer
I have a reducer inside useContext/provider. I need to validate an action using values from another Provider. Is there a way to retrieve those values from a Provider from within the useReducer hook? Or do I have to try to feed them in as function arguments. Ex:
Reducer
export default function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "set-amount": {
            const { amount } = action.state
            const { maxAmount } = useFooContext()

            if (amount > maxAmount) // do something

            return { ...state, amount }
        }
    }
}

Provider
export function Provider(...) {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {}, initState)
    return ...
}

=== EDIT per @Drew
Wondering if I'm following what you said, does this look right?
// provider
export default function Provider( ... ) {
    const foo = useFooContext()
    const fooRef = React.useRef(foo)

    const reducerFn = useMemo( () => {
        fooRef.current = foo
        return reducer( fooRef )
    }, [foo])

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer( reducerFn, {}, initState)

    return ( ... )
}

// reducer
export default function(ref: React.MutableRefObject<Foo>) {
    return function(state: State, action: Action): State {
        ...
        fooRef.current.value != value
        ...
    }
}


You can't call React hooks in nested functions, this breaks React's Rules of Hooks, only call hooks at the top-level in React functions and custom hooks.
I suggest re-writing the reducer function to curry the Foo context value when it's instantiated.
Example:
const reducer = (fooContext: FooContext) => (state: State, action: Action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "set-amount": {
      const { amount } = action.state;
      const { maxAmount } = fooContext;

      if (amount > maxAmount) // do something

      return { ...state, amount }
    }

    ...
  }
};

export default reducer;

export function Provider(...) {
  const fooContext = useFooContext();

  const reducerFn = useMemo(() => reducer(fooContext), []);

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducerFn, {}, initState);

  return ...
}

If you need to access non-static values then you could return a "getState" method the fooContext could access, or save fooContext into a React ref that is passed to the curried reducer function so it can access whatever the current context value is each time.

This is exactly what I was looking for, TY @Drew! It is non-static, so I'll try to create the getState method

@Sean Awesome, happy to help. Cheers and good luck!

added an edit, is that what you were describing? I'm not sure if I'm using useRef correctly.

Or maybe that's wrong because it's recreating the reducer on every rerender?

@Sean You shouldn't update your post, but yes, very close to that, something like const reducerFn = useMemo(() => reducer(fooRef), []) where you just pass the ref into the reducer function, and just before that the fooRef.current = foo so the ref is always set to the current foo context value. Then in your reducer access fooRef.current.X for whatever you need.

@Sean I used an empty dependency array in my answer so the reducer function is created only once, and it's the ref that is dynamically updated.
